# Considering Cassette Upgrade

Tags: road-bike, derailleur

I'm considering upgrading from a 9-speed, 12-26 cassette on a 2006 Lemond Alpe D'Huez.  I have a triple front chairing with a Shimano 105 groupset, with one exception - an Ultegra rear derailleur.  Can I do this by changing both derailleurs, the chain, the cassette, and the hub on my existing rear wheel?  I have a lot of hills in my area, which is why I'm looking into possibly a 10 speed, 12-30.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can, but will also need a new 10sp derailleur, 10sp chain and 10sp 'brifter' (brake/shift lever) . Your hub will fit a 10sp cassette. You may be able to fit a 9sp 11-32 cassette or even larger depending on if you have a long or short cage derailleur. Search this bicycles Stack Echange, lots of info on both these options.

Comment: You have triple and you still need a lower gear for climbing?  What is your small chain ring tooth count?   That is a bit of money for one more gear and an older bike.

Comment: 10 speed Shimano road changes cable pull versus 9 speed, so you do need to swap the derailleur. You shouldn't need to swap the hub. Why not get a 9 speed 12-30 and be done with it?

Comment: Triples typically have long cage derailleurs, so even a rear 12-32 should be possible, but then most probably with a longer chain!